# SharedPreferences lost when onCreate is called again

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have the following situation:

One activity that is updated from a service. When the update is made, some preferences are written. Everything fine so far.
When the activity is not visible and the service decides to do an update, I get a notification. Clicking on this notification opens the activity where I expect to find the previously stored preferences, but nothing is there.

I saw that when clicking on the notification the onCreate() method of the activity is called and this is where I create an arrayadapter which contains the preferences, unfortunately the preferences are somehow not there.

Please keep in mind that:

- I use commit() when I update the preferences
- I access the SharedPreferences this way (when reading and when writing):

  SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
              SHARED_PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

where `SHARED_PREF_FILE` is a constant. While debugging I found out that the `sharedPref` object is pointing to the same xml file (/data/data/........xml), so this should be okay.

Best regards

Edit (some code):

I have a class (`PrefManager`) managing the SharedPreferences:

```
public static Set<String> retrieveData(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            SHARED_PREF_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE | Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
    return sharedPref.getStringSet(MY_KEY,
            new HashSet<String>());
}
```

In the Activity's onCreate() I have this:

```
myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PrefManager.retrieveData(this));
```

Comment: What's MY_KEY? Won't you need retrieveData(Context context, String key)?

Comment: `MY_KEY` is (like `SHARED_PREF_FILE`) a constant I've declared. My preferences are storing only one type of information, therefore I need only one key, that's why I defined it like this

Comment: I am starting to think that this has something to do with preferenced assigned only to a specific activity. When debugging, I noticed that the context object changes (which I guess is ok given the fact that onCreate is called) but the SharedPreferences object stays the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, in case someone stumbles upon this:

I was able to make it work by adding this to the intent that was used for the creation of the notification:

`intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);`